# Vim: how to delete whitespace in blank lines?

Tags: vim, vi

How can I use vim to detect blank lines containing whitespace and delete the whitespace?

For example, I use `⎵` to represent whitespace:

```py
def⎵function(foo):
⎵⎵⎵⎵print(foo) 
⎵⎵
⎵
function(1)
```

Is there a vim command that converts the code above to the following?

```py
def⎵function(foo):
⎵⎵⎵⎵print(foo) 


function(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:g/^\s\+$/s/\s\+//
```

Explanation:

```
g — execute the command globally (for all lines)
/^\s\+$/ — search lines that contain only whitespaces
s/\s\+// — for every found line execute this
           search and replace command:
           search whitespaces and replace with an empty string.
```

Could be simplified as

```
:%s/^\s\+$//

% — execute for all lines
s/^\s\+$// — search and replace command:
             search lines that only have whitespaces
             and replace with an empty string.
```

Comment: any reason to `:g` here instead of `:%s`?

Comment: @Michail Updated, thanks! I'm accustomed to `:g` because I usually delete empty lines with `:g/^$/normal dd` :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have a function that solves this problem and keeps your cursor position

```
if !exists('*StripTrailingWhitespace')
    function! StripTrailingWhitespace()
        if !&binary && &filetype != 'diff'
            let b:win_view = winsaveview()
            silent! keepjumps keeppatterns %s/\s\+$//e
            call winrestview(b:win_view)
        endif
    endfunction
endif
command! Cls call StripTrailingWhitespace()
cnoreabbrev cls Cls
cnoreabbrev StripTrailingSpace Cls
nnoremap <Leader>s :call StripTrailingWhitespace()
```

You can use a command `:cls` or a shortcut `<leader>s`. 
Actually you can change it to fit your needs.